# How do I go into Blitz Play?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After I've gotten the masks, trash truck and tow truck, I hide the getaway car and can't progress to the actual heist. I've been stuck here for about 5 months. Do I need to play the other side mission in order for the heist to show up? I'm really confused on what needs to happen next. I played for hours and still no blitz play.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few prerequisites to starting this mission. Each character has side missions that must be completed before the actual heist can be played.

- Franklin will receive a call from Lester. Go to Lester to start the mission:
- > [The Hotel Assassination](http://gta.wikia.com/The_Hotel_Assassination)
- Trevor will need to go to Floyd's apartment to start the mission:
- > [Scouting the Port](http://gta.wikia.com/Scouting_the_Port)
- Either Franklin or Trevor can head to Franklin's home to start the mission:
- > [Hood Safari](http://gta.wikia.com/Hood_Safari)
- As Michael, head to his home to start the mission:
- > [Did Somebody Say Yoga?](http://gta.wikia.com/Did_Somebody_Say_Yoga%3F)

Comment: Yessssss!!!! That did it!!!!! Thank you so much. This is a burden off my shoulders now.  You were a great help .

Comment: I can't find `Hood safari` anywhere at both of frank's safe houses. Not by by frank or by trevor. is there any prerequisite for the Hood safari as well?

Comment: Did all of them, no dice.

Comment: Joshi, Hood Safari starts with a cutscene where Trevor shows up at Franklin's.  They go to drug deal (Lamar's, so you know what to expect).  Trevor is suspicious, it turns out the dealer tried to trick them, and ends in a big fat shootout.  I have done it ages ago, just didn't pay attention to the mission names.